# What do you call being "on hold" on the telephone in German?

Tags: translation, english-to-german, phrase-request

In the situation that someone (in the room) might ask you,

> Sind Sie am Telefon?

and I am indeed on a call but being on hold, and thus I can still speak while waiting to be put through, I'd like to say the equivalent of.

> Yes, but we can still talk, I'm on hold.

-

> Ja, aber wir können trotzdem sprechen. Ich bin .....[on hold]........

Comment: You are on hold and you know this because there is elevator music playing in the background or there is no sound at all? Then the party at the other end of the line asks you, Are you on the phone (= Are you still there?) Have I got that right so far? Then why would you answer "Yes, but we can still talk, I'm on hold."?

Comment: Oh wait I get it, the person asking you is in the room with you. NEVER MIND :)

Comment: Aside, I would phrase the first part: "Ja, aber wir können dennoch[or trotzdem] sprechen."

Comment: I rephrased the second sentence as I had trouble to understand what is being ask. Hopefully, I didn't changed the initial idea.

Comment: Note that a lot of people have unwittingly made embarrassing confessions while being put "on hold". Just because you can't hear what people at the other end of the line are saying, doesn't mean that they can't hear you ;)

Comment: ...aber ich höre noch Fahrstuhlmusik

Comment: @Em1 Thanks for the hint, I've updated the question to reflect that.

Comment: The first question sounds unusual. Something like "Oh, störe ich? Telefonieren Sie gerade?" is more common.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> "...ich hänge in der Warteschleife."

Comment: wer nicht *"hängen"* will, kann auch *"sich befinden"* oder *"sein"* ;)

Comment: @takkat Zumindest die erste Alternative ist im mündlichen Sprachgebrauch eher selten.

Answer (score 1):

Die Warteschleife hat die Konnotation eines professionellen Gegenübers, obwohl es möglicherweise dieselbe Technik wie bei privaten Telefonen ist. Ohne diese Konotation gäbe es noch die umgangssprachliche Alternative:

> Ich wurde weggedrückt. / Ich bin weggedrückt (worden).

Die wird auch verwendet, wenn das Gespräch von Vornherein abgelehnt wurde. (Dank an Stefan Walter für diesen Hinweis.)

Comment: "weggedrückt" heißt für mich, dass mein Gegenüber das Gespräch komplett ablehnt, indem er die rote Taste drückt.

Comment: @StefanWalter Ich kenne es für beide Sachen. Es ergibt sich meist aus dem Kontext. Wenn ich vorher gesprochen habe, bevor ich das sage, dann wurde das Gespräch wohl nicht abgelehnt.

Comment: Ich kennne "weggedrückt" aus dem Radio und da wird es immer dann benutzt wenn der Moderator aus Versehen jemanden aus der Leitung schmeißt. Ich glaube der Punkt ist, dass, wer weggedrückt ist, nicht einfach wieder dazugedrückt werden kann.